# How to get image data from CCfits

Tags: c++, image, fits

I'm trying to read and write FITS images using C++. I'm trying to use CCfits, but I can't figure out how how to get the pixel buffer. I have used the sample code in the documentation to successfully read the image and print out the primary header, but I get an error when I tried to read the binary data array. Here is the code provided in the CCfits example (I've indicated where the error is).

```
int readImage()
{
    std::auto_ptr<FITS> pInfile(new FITS("atestfil.fit",Read,true));
    PHDU& image = pInfile->pHDU();
    std::valarray<unsigned long>  contents;

    // read all user-specifed, coordinate, and checksum keys in the image
    image.readAllKeys();
    image.read(contents); // !!!ERROR HERE!!!

    // this doesn’t print the data, just header info.
    std::cout << image << std::endl;
    long ax1(image.axis(0));
    long ax2(image.axis(1));

    for (long j = 0; j < ax2; j+=10)
    {
        std::ostream_iterator<short> c(std::cout,"\t");
        std::copy(&contents[j*ax1], &contents[(j+1)*ax1-1], c);
        std::cout << '\n';
    {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error returned from make is:

```
undefined reference to `void CCfits::PHDU::read<unsigned long>(std::valarray<unsigned long>&)'
```

And indeed, according to the documentation I downloaded with the source code there is no function with that signature. So I tried all the other signatures that are documented, but I still get basically the same error (just a different signature mentioned).

In fact, I opened up my local copy of *PHDU.h* and found this line:

```
 template<typename S>
        void read(std::valarray<S>& image) ;
```

I am including `-lcfitsio -lCCfits`, and the code builds fine if I comment out the the line with the *read()* function.

**Does any body know how to use this library?**

**Does anyone have a working example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears CCfits doesn't really work as advertised. The *read()* function is documented and even declared in the header file, but there is no implementation.

Just use cfitsio, it works.

Comment: Not sure what source code you downloaded, but there is such a function, and here it is: `template <typename S>         void PHDU::read (std::valarray<S>& image)         {                 long init(1);                 long nElements(std::accumulate(naxes().begin(),naxes().end(),init,                                 std::multiplies<long>()));                  read(image,1,nElements,static_cast<S*>(0));         }` It does not crash for me on read. Installed the default versions for ubuntu 18.04 via apt

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, in order for CCfits to work properly, you NEED to use `#include <CCfits>`. Including just the files you *think* you need doesn't pull in the implementations of the functions.

I've also found that you need to modify the code a bit, and specify a valarray of non-zero length (at least for a newer gcc version (8.x.y)).

Comment: I found it was easier to just use cfitsio.